# Hide current div and show previous div on browser back button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I have a site that has multiple pages. I created these multiple pages by showing and hiding divs that are located on one html file. The problem I am running into is that the back and forward buttons in the browser don't work with this method. How can I bind these buttons to my jQuery show/hide events so that when I, for example, click the back button in the browser, the current div hides and the previous div shows? Is this even possible simply with jQuery, HTML, and CSS?

Comment: perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I get a general sense of what you're trying to accomplish here. In the example below, I used `.click()` events as the trigger to get the **current** page number, then add or subtract one from the number to get the id of the **target** page, convert it to a string, then hide/display pages based on that information.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var page = 1; //current page
  $('#pg2').hide();
  $('#pg3').hide();
  $('#fwd').click(function() {
    var currentPage = "#pg" + page.toString();
    $(currentPage).hide();
    page++;
    var nextPage = "#pg" + page.toString();
    $(nextPage).show();
  });
  $('#bck').click(function() {
    var currentPage = "#pg" + page.toString();
    $(currentPage).hide();
    page--;
    var nextPage = "#pg" + page.toString();
    $(nextPage).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bck">back</button>
<button id="fwd">forward</button>
<div id="pg1"><p>page 1</p></div>
<div id="pg2"><p>page 2</p></div>
<div id="pg3"><p>page 3</p></div>
```